# Docker Compose: Rails won't respect the DATABASE_URL to connect to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to containerize my Ruby on Rails 5.1.0 application, but I'm having some trouble with it not picking up `DATABASE_URL` from the environment. In `docker-compose.yml`, I have the following service:

```
app:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  environment:
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:pw@db:5432/myapp_development
```

The environment gets picked up just fine if I run `docker-compose run app rails c`:

```
$ docker-compose run app rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 25
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.0)
irb(main):001:0> ENV['DATABASE_URL']
=> "postgres://postgres:pw@db:5432/myapp_development"
```

But then if I run `docker-compose run app rake db:create`, I get an error about not being able to connect to `localhost`:

```
$ docker-compose run app rake db:create
Database 'myapp_development' already exists
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>10, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"myapp_test"}
rake aborted!
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: Here's what `database.yml` looks like:

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *common
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *common
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *common
  database: myapp_production
```

Comment: I can share with you my solution, but it  does't direct answer your question, so i put it in comment.  You can add separated container to postgres, add host config to your database.yml that match postgres container name.  Then log into container and you will be able to run any  command you want without errors.I can put detailed answer if you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar issue, the causes of which were multi-fold.

TL;DR, make sure that:

1. Your `app` container is correctly linked to and dependent on your `postgres` container
2. Your `DATABASE_URL` references the correct hostname of your `postgres` container
3. The `RAILS_ENV` ENV variable is explicitly set within your `app` container

First off, I had to make sure my `app` container in `docker_compose.yml` was linked to and depended on the `postgres` container:

```
version: '3'
    services:
      app:
        container_name: 'app'
        depends_on:
          - postgres
        links:
          - postgres
```

Second, the `DATABASE_URL` ENV variable I was providing `database.yml` did not reference the correct hostname of the postgres container. Originally, mine looked like:

`'postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/my_app_development'`

I changed it to:

`'postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/my_app_development'`

Not an apparent issue in your case, but worth noting for others.

Third, I wasn't explicitly specifying the `RAILS_ENV` environment. I set that ENV variable to `development` in `docker_compose.yml` so that the correct `database.yml` configuration was used.

The end result of my `database.yml` file:

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_development
  username: postgres
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test
  pool: 5
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

The end result of my `docker_compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: 'app'
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/my_app_development'
      RAILS_ENV: 'development'
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./:/dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    tty: true

  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
```

After that, all `bundle exec rake db:` commands worked just fine.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the rake task, it is trying to create the test database, I assume your `database.yml` has a test environment with `localhost` host.

From the description of `rake db:create`

> Creates the database from DATABASE_URL or **config/database.yml** for the
>   current RAILS_ENV (use db:create:all to create all databases in the
>   config). **Without RAILS_ENV it defaults to creating the development and
>   *test databases***

You should pass the env evidently or it could create a test database by default.

I suggest you to change the test database credentionals in the `database.yml`.

[`Connection Preference`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference)

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't understand why it tells me to that `myapp_development` already exists, and then doesn't connect when trying to create `myapp_test` – in `database.yml` they connect to the same place. I'll edit my answer to include `database.yml`.

Comment: I don't get your comment. Change the database.yml and set the host _evidently_ in the both environments.

Comment: But isn't it the case that I don't need to set the host if I'm providing a `DATABASE_URL` in the environment?

Comment: Yes, it is. Looks like for some reason the env varaible was not exported.

Comment: Also the matter thing is in some cases the database.yml have the preference over env configuration.

Comment: I had initially thought the env var wasn't exported, but running `rails c` in the same way shows that it is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it seems like the config merging is somehow broken on Rails 5.1.x

You can force the use of `DATABASE_URL` by adding `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` in your `default` block.

Answer (score 0):

I think [@Зелёныйenter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44070837/2553863) is mostly correct, the problem is that the rake task is trying to create databases for development and test.

The line

```
Database 'myapp_development' already exists
```

is probably there because the DB was created in a previous execution of the same command, that created the DB and also failed in trying to create the test DB.

One would think that by specifying the DB name in the URL, in this case myapp_development

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:pw@db:5432/myapp_development
```

that would be the only DB to create, but it is not. I used DATABASE_URL without specifying the DB name, like:

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:pw@db:5432
```

with the same result, one created, one failed.

As I understand, however, this is not a problem of RAILS_ENV definition. **This is expected behaviour**, according to [this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27299#issuecomment-295855603) on an issue about this very subject, which by the way, is still in discussion.

So far, there are [3 suggested workarounds](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27299#issuecomment-522034963): two are gems, and the other is the modification or elimination of database.yml.

One possible database.yml that works is:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
```

Which will create both databases without error.